# Rename a workspace in xcode 4

Tags: xcode

Does anybody know how to rename a workspace in Xcode 4 (not a project in a workspace)?
It might be simple but can't find it...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it...
Just rename the file in the filesystem...

Comment: You might have to restart Xcode, closing the workspace wasn't enough for me. Xcode was still thinking that some sub-project was opened by the old (renamed) workspace.