# How do you rename a workspace?

Tags: xcode

I need to rename my workspace from "ABC DEF" to "ABCDEF", closing it and then simply renaming it in the filesystem (as suggested here, [Rename a workspace in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977179/rename-a-workspace-in-xcode-4)) doesn't work as when I subsequently build it I get an error saying "ABC DEF.xcworkspace" is a missing file.

Before and after renaming it I cleaned the build and deleted Derived Data in Organizer, but there must be something residual somewhere called "ABC DEF", but where?

Version 4.5

Answer (score 4):

Renaming in the file system does work BUT I had to clean / exit / relaunch / Xcode twice to remove residual references to the old name!